# PHP in Windows 2008 64-bit slow

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, php5

I have un 4GB RAM AMD Opteron machine (3.2GHz quad) on 64-bit Win2k8 RS2 -- installed Apache Lounge 32-bit version (as general consensus is no big speed win between 32-bit and 64-bit) with thread-safe VC9 PHP 5.3.8.

First byte out on Apache is ok, with mod_deflate, there is a slight betterment over the old Intel 1GB machine. PHP via Apache (as module) and PHP as CLI takes 1 sec for script that takes the old box just over half that time.

MySQL is running fine and fast (64-bit). hosts file is not the probleme.

What settings I should be checking to make the whole PHP proces faster?

TIA,
YP

Comment: Profile your code to see what the bottleneck is?  See xdebug

Comment: currently a for loop running 10000 times, with multiplication; i testing on simple 10 line loop...

Comment: @Zoredache currently is `<?php $a=0; $b=1; for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) { $a += 1; $b = $a / $b; }`

Answer (score 0):

You're measuring how well a mathematician can run the 100 yard dash. You can probably get him to do it a bit better with effort, but why not see how well he solves math problems instead?

In other words, test under realistic conditions.

Comment: I agree, but still it seems concerning, that a simple loop would be twice as slow on faster hardware.